# Why do these two equations equal?

Tags: calculus

I know this is an easy problem but for some reason I don't know the rule behind it. Why does:

[image]

Can somebody explain this to me please?

Thanks!

Comment: Just put everything under a common denominator and calculate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because
$$1-\frac{k_B}{k_A+k_B}=\frac{k_A+k_B}{k_A+k_B}-\frac{k_B}{k_A+k_B}=\frac{(k_A+k_B)-k_B}{k_A+k_B}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Getting a common denominator helps. Rewrite 1 as $\frac{k_a+k_b}{k_a+k_b}$. Does this help, or would you like more hints?